# What does the size of a SQL table depend on?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I mean SQL here can be any SQL like database such as SQL server, My SQL, SQLite, even MS Access. I want to know what the size of a table depends on, it depends on the actual rows in the table with a fixedly designed structure or it also depends on the content of cells in the table. For example:

I have a table which has the fixedly designed structure like this:

```
create table SampleTable (
   ID int primary key,
   Message varchar(500)
)
```

And here is the table with 1 row:

```
ID    |     Message
1           I love .NET     --11 characters for Message
```

and here is also a table with 1 row:

```
ID    |     Message
1           I also love Java     --16 characters for Message
```

If the size depends on the number of rows, the 2 tables above would have the same size, if it also depends on the cells' content, the second table would have the larger size. I would like to know which is larger? I care about this because, in some case, I really want to maximize the maximum number of characters for a field (8000 in SQL server), to make user free from inputting almost anything s/he wants, but I'm afraid of making my database file too large (unnecessarily, costly).

Comment: Implementation dependant. In SQL Server fixed length datatypes use the full declared datatype. variable length ones just size of contents. Except if using compression when fixed length ones are stored as variable length. Also has a sparse column format that is different again. Overdeclaring column widths can have implications for memory allocations however.

Comment: If going cheap prevents you from meeting your business requirements, it's a bad idea,

Comment: For SQL Server, MSDN [explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175991.aspx) how to estimate table size for tables and indexes. The same general idea probably applies to other platforms.

Comment: If you really want to give them freedom, why not use a `text` datatype?  It gives even more freedom.

Comment: It looks like that the structure determines almost the size of the table. If so I think XML would be better in this case. I don't know well about compression in SQL database, is it used to collapse all the redundant space (I suppose that designed size = actual data size + redundant space)?

Comment: @KingBoy Even if your primary consideration for storage of your data is the size on disk, I doubt you would want to use XML.

Answer (score 3):

A varchar (or nvarchar) field only uses the space in which is required.

As such smaller amounts of data take up less space. Fixed length equivalents (char, nchar) use the full length.

The storage size of a varchar field is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Roughly speaking, the size of a table depends on

- the size of fixed-width columns (integer, float, char(n), etc.), plus
- the size of data in variable-width columns (varchar(n), clob, etc.), plus
- the size of indexes, plus
- index overhead, plus
- table overhead, plus
- row overhead, plus
- column overhead, minus
- compression and other internal optimizations that I can't think of right now.

Overhead can surprise you.

Partitioning and other structural optimizations can affect what you mean by *table*.

Answer (score 2):

*SQL* - meaning the ISO SQL Standard - actually specifies nothing about how data should be stored. Different DBMSs all have their own internal storage mechanisms and they can vary widely.

Indexing, compression and partitioning are just some of the factors to determine how much storage is used. You need to refer to the documentation for the specific product you are using rather than looking for any general answer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking. At least for SQL Server there are way to many factors to take into account:

- data types stored on each column (varchar as you example, int, bigint, datetime) each one uses some amount of space
- indexes on the table
- type of indexes on the table
- ...and some more

Check on books online about [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) and for each one how much storage it takes to save it.

See for example how to [calculate the estimated size of a clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178085.aspx) in MS SQL Server.

Same for a [non clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190620.aspx).